# How to display html code which is load from db in jsf screen?

Tags: jsf

I have html code in one column. Loaded html code to one bean.
My question is how to display this html code using jsf tags.

Answer (score 6):

You can use a `<h:outputText>` component, and set `escape="false"`.

Comment: Thank you romaintaz. i have one more doubt. I loaded the data from db and set to beans. It diplay in screen. Suppose if i click any button in same screen, the data loaded again from db. All beans are null for every request. That is the reason i am unable to stop the loading. Can you please tell me how to resolve this issue?

Comment: @venkat Please create another question (as it is a different problem), and post some code to explain the situation.